# How do I make the method accept it's input during it?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment in class but we are required to use the teachers skeleton code instead of designing it our own way. The comments are the instructions for the method and the method is what I have so far, but I still don't understand how it should work. What confuses me is that it needs to print the options before the user knows what to do, so how can you run the method without having the input first?

```
/**
* Prints the main menu (see output examples), allows the user to make a selection from available operations
*
* @param input the Scanner object you created at the beginning of the main
* method. Any value other than the 4 valid selections should generate an
* invalid value prompt. Print the list again and prompt user to select a 
* valid value from the list.

* @return an integer from 1-4 inclusive representing the user’s selection.

*/

public static int mainMenuOptionSelector(Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Please select an option from the list below:");
    System.out.println("1. Check the balance of your account");
    System.out.println("2. Make a deposit");
    System.out.println("3. Withdraw an amount in a specific currency");
    System.out.println("4. End your session (and withdraw all remaining currency in U.S. Dollars)");

    if(input.equals(1))
        return 1;
    else if(input.equals(2))
        return 2;
    else if(input.equals(3))
        return 3;

    else if(input.equals(4))
        return 4;
    else{
        System.out.println("Input falied validation.");
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `input.equals(1)` doesn't make any sense. This code seems very broken.

Comment: You may find [Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) helpful. That is, in your code, a call to `input.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes a [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as input (unless your teacher has rolled his own Scanner, which would be bad naming practice). Scanner provides methods to read data in from a variety of sources, such as the keyboard (typically `System.in`).

One of these methods is [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), which reads the next `int` from the scanner's input and returns it. You can do something like this:

```
theSelection = input.nextInt();
```

And then, you can reference the new variable `theSelection` as you would any other int. Just beware that the `nextInt` method can throw a number of runtime exceptions that you probably want to catch and handle gracefully.